# Remove a module when building application using ng build

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular9, angular10

I have a scenario where one of the module should not be there based on configuration when building an angular application using ng build.

Let us suppose I have three modules home, about, other (have nested routing like otherone and othertwo) each one has routing links on the app.component.html, is there any way to remove module named other from bundle(from the build) based on configuration.
I am not using webpack, I am using angular build(angular.json) to build the application.

example: remove leaves module from build bundle(https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-routing-with-modules-with-bootstrap)
one way is to comment lazyloading of leaves modules in app-routing.module.ts, is there any programmatic way of doing it?

Comment: The Angular CLI uses webpack under the hood, so if you are using the angular CLI then you are using Webpack.  My only idea is to move everything to a library and create two separate apps; but that is a lot of overhead.

Comment: in Angular.json you can replace the routing file with another one to not include the module, but so the modue will remain but it'll be forever inaccessible